# PHP file get html doesnt return anything

Tags: php

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("https://www.psacard.com/cert/43696531");
echo $html;
```

This will not print anything out for me, but I will get it from other websites. Any specific reason why?

file_get_contents also returns nothing.

```
  $url = "https://www.psacard.com/cert/43696531";

  $options = array(
   'http' => array(
     'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
     'method'  => 'GET',
   )
  );
  $context  = stream_context_create($options);
  $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  $string = preg_replace('/\s+/S', " ", $result);
  if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
  $stringVal = strval($string);
  echo $stringVal;
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting on?  What does view source in the browser show?

Comment: the view source is empty @AbraCadaver

Comment: try using file_get_contents instead and see if you're still getting nothing

Comment: I tried that also. Still shows nothing... Ill post my code above. @PHPGuru

Comment: The content-type header is wrong but fixing that didn't fix the issue for me. It still doesn't work. I think the problem is caused by Cloudflare. They could be blocking you because you don't support HTTP/2.

Comment: I see that too. I was able to set it properly with Puppeteer/Node so I may have to go that route.

Comment: Fixing the content-type header won't fix the problem which is that the site is responding with a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable over HTTP/1.1